# CSS is not loading properly on mac OS safari and chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

For the website i made CSS is not loading properly for Apple devices.

I maintained all the media query statements and style sheets separately. Hence it is not displaying properly in MAC OS safari and chrome. But rest all browsers and devices is fine.

link: <kbd>[referencelink](http://kaplankesdeeexampreps.com/KESDEE_NEWUI/buyOnline.html)</kbd>

```
<link href="css/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 390px)" />
<link href="css/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 391px) and (max-width: 500px)" />
<link href="css/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 768px)" />
<link href="css/medium.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 769px)" />
```

This query only i maintained for fluidity. Guys help me out

Answer (score 1):

Create one CSS file and put all the code inside this using following technic.

HTML:

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

style.css code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 390px) {
/* 
*** Add CSS proparty ***
*/
}

@media screen and (min-width: 391px) {
/* 
*** Add CSS proparty ***
*/
}

@media screen and (min-width: 501px) {
/* 
*** Add CSS proparty ***
*/
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
/* 
*** Add CSS proparty ***
*/
}
```

It is tested. I use it in every project.

Comment: i tried with another conditional statement

`<script>
 function loadCSS(){
  
 if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 
  $("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/mobile.css' />");
  
  }
  else
  {
  
  $("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/medium.css' />");
  
  }
 
 }
 loadCSS();
 </script>`

its perfectly alright in android and windows devices but MAC OS and Apple devices doesnt loading styles in a proper order/manner

Comment: its 1500 lines of code for each css. so need to find another solution

Comment: java script is loading while creating dom faster than css so i made a statement to detect device and load css. Still i have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create CSS file and put the code inside the following technique

@media (min-width: 500px ) and (max-width: 800px)  {  

/* CSS property */ 

}
```

Comment: javascript is loading while creating dom faster than css so i made a statement to detect device and load css. Still i have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The same happened with me while I was developing my first web page using the text editor in mac.

I solved my problem by adjusting the quotation marks in keyboards. For that go to

> preferences > keyboard > text

in the right side you'll find double quotes and single quotes. Select the option which has a simple type of quotes.